# How to select many folders and file to work on

Tags: python, vcf-variant-call-format

the present script runs on two files within the same folder. 
Each time I have to run a different case, I have to replace the path in the script with the right folder (i.e 11221 instead of 11220) and the right file names within that folder (i.e. 11221_S1 instead of 11220_S1) and run the script again.

Is there a way to make the script select all the folders contained in /mypath and inside that folder select the two files i need for the script to run? so i would not need to replace manually the text in the script for each file.

thank you in advance
Luca

```
import sys
infile=open("mypath/11220/11220_S1.vcf")
outfile=open('/mypath/11220/11220_S1.csv', 'w')
outfile2=open('/mypath/11220_S1.txt', 'w') 
    for line in infile:
        data=line.split()
        if data[0] == "#CHROM":
            #print line
            outfile.write(str(data[0]) + '\t' +  str(data[1]) + '\t' +str(data[3]) + '\t' +str(data[4])  + '\t'+ str('SDP') + '\t'+ str('DP') + '\t'+ str('RD') + '\t'+ str('AD') + '\t'+ str('FREQ') + '\t'+ str('PVALUE') +'\t' + '\n')
            outfile2.write(str("chrom") + '\t' +  str("position") + '\n')
        if data[0] == "chr17":
            tag=data[9].split(":")
            #print tag[3]
            outfile.write(str(data[0]) + '\t' +  str(data[1]) + '\t' +str(data[3]) + '\t' +str(data[4])  + '\t'+ str(tag[2]) + '\t'+ str(tag[3]) + '\t'+ str(tag[4]) + '\t'+ str(tag[5]) + '\t'+ str(tag[6]) + '\t'+ str(tag[7]) +'\t'  + '\n')
            outfile2.write(str(data[0]) + '\t' +  str(data[1]) + '\n')

    outfile.close()
    outfile2.close()


infile=open("mypath/11220/11220_S2.vcf")
outfile=open('/mypath/11220/11220_S2.csv', 'w')
outfile2=open('/mypath/11220_S2.txt', 'w') 
    for line in infile:
        data=line.split()
        if data[0] == "#CHROM":
            #print line
            outfile.write(str(data[0]) + '\t' +  str(data[1]) + '\t' +str(data[3]) + '\t' +str(data[4])  + '\t'+ str('SDP') + '\t'+ str('DP') + '\t'+ str('RD') + '\t'+ str('AD') + '\t'+ str('FREQ') + '\t'+ str('PVALUE') +'\t' + '\n')
            outfile2.write(str("chrom") + '\t' +  str("position") + '\n')
        if data[0] == "chr17":
            tag=data[9].split(":")
            #print tag[3]
            outfile.write(str(data[0]) + '\t' +  str(data[1]) + '\t' +str(data[3]) + '\t' +str(data[4])  + '\t'+ str(tag[2]) + '\t'+ str(tag[3]) + '\t'+ str(tag[4]) + '\t'+ str(tag[5]) + '\t'+ str(tag[6]) + '\t'+ str(tag[7]) +'\t'  + '\n')
            outfile2.write(str(data[0]) + '\t' +  str(data[1]) + '\n')

    outfile.close()
    outfile2.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hardcoding each file path, you could use glob (https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) for Unix-like selections. Rough examples of how glob can be used:

```
import glob
filepath = glob.glob('mypath/11220/*.vcf')[0]
infile = open(logpath, "r")
```

or

```
import glob
filepath = glob.glob('mypath/1122*/*.vcf')[0]
infile = open(logpath, "r")
```

and so on.

Best of luck to you!